# Sitecore Server Error in Core database when viewing Template Inheritance tab

Tags: sitecore

I have Sitecore 6.5 rev. 111230 installed and am getting a server error when I am trying to view the inheritance tab of any template in the Core database. Here is a screenshot of the error I am getting:

[image: System.InvalidOperationException: fieldTypeItem]

I already checked the versions of my Sitecore.Kernel.dll and Sitecore.Client.dll and they match up with the Sitecore revision I have installed.

I've also confirmed that the templates are correctly inheriting from the base template.

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: Good to see you found a fix. I wonder how it can be broken in my default installation though :)

Comment: I have just posted this issue to Sitecore Support and will comment with any updates

Comment: Here is the response for Support (AND IT WORKS!):
"As a workaround, please set field type of the __Owner field of /sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Security item in the core database to Text or Single-Line Text."

Answer (score 1):

This was registered as a bug in the Sitecore client.  The problem is the wrong data type for one of the fields.

Here's the fix in case you can't upgrade--

> Go to /sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Security in core
>   database and assign a "Single-Line Text" field type to the __Owner
>   field.

Answer (score 0):

You should contact Sitecore Support about this because it looks like this happens with every  default installation of Sitecore 6.5

I have just tried it and the exact same problem occurs on my (clean) installation.

Let me know if you don't have access to Sitecore support. Then i will create a support case about it.

Comment: I also have this same issue on a 6.5 instance in the Core.